# logging standard python exceptions with django

Tags: python, django

In one of my views, I handle a general python exception.  This exception does not crash the site, or result in a 500.

I would like to log this exception with django so that I can inspect it.  What is the pythonic and djangonic [??] why to do this?

```
def Set( request ):
    if request.POST:
         try:
             #something nearly impossible
         except Exception as exc:
             #where do I log this?
             pass

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'ya':'hoo!'}), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: The built-in standard Python logging doesn't work in django? http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html

Comment: sentry and raven play nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard logging module provides all you need - in this case, `logger.exception()`:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("your-logger-name")

def Set(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            #something nearly impossible
        except Exception as exc:
            #where do I log this?
            logger.exception("some exception message")
```

Then you just have to properly configure your logger in your `settings.py` as documented in Django's FineManual(tm).

Comment: Thank you... But how to get the full stack trace?

Comment: `logger.exception` does log the whole thing - that's the point.